# Javascript/jQuery change <img src=" "> onclick with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating kind of a slideshow in jQuery and on each click of the next button, I need the image src to increase. The file names of the images are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11, so I tried using a for loop. But since I'm no javascript/jquery guru, I can't think of other ways to solve my issue and make it actually work.

With my code, nothing happens at all.

This is what I've tried:

```
$('#right_arrow').click(function()
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        $('#produkti').attr('src', 'style/images/produktet/' + i + '.gif');
    }
});
```

And this is the actual html for the image:

```
<img src="style/images/produktet/1.gif" alt="Produkti 1" id="produkti" />
```

Comment: you can not assign one id to same 11 images, it will never work, jquery/javascript will always pick the first element with specified id. you should use class and pick image element by index.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7x8kg/ delete the `div` part. That is to see the change

Comment: @Bondye Your solution worked! Is there a way to tell me how to do the opposite of this? Not increase but decrease AND a way to add a jQuery transition to this, possibly animate.

Comment: @Dugi http://jsfiddle.net/7x8kg/3/ edited into both

Comment: @Dugi +a little animation, edit yourself because I don't know how you want to animate. http://jsfiddle.net/7x8kg/5/

Answer (score 2):

you can not assign one id to same 11 images, it will never work, jquery/javascript will always pick the first element with specified id.

You should use class and pick image element by index.

```
$('#right_arrow').click(function()
{
    for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
    {
        $('.produkti').get(i-1).attr('src', 'style/images/produktet/' + i + '.gif');
    }
});
```

and html here:

```
<img src="style/images/produktet/6.gif" alt="Produkti 6" class="produkti" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is - Every time you click that button, the index will return to 1.
`for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++)`

What you'll need to do, is have a global variable .. say `var imgIndex` Then, your code should be -
`// somewhere ABOVE.. probably the head tag...
var imgIndex = 0;`

```
$('#right_arrow').click(function()
{
  $('#produkti').attr('src', 'style/images/produktet/' + imgIndex + '.gif');
  imgIndex++;
});
```

Keep in mind you'll have to reset this imgIndex value when it reaches max.

Comment: Edited my post accordingly.. realized it after i took a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do this with an "auto loop" (when right arrow is clicked and current image is number 11, current image will be number 1)

```
var current = 6;
$('#right_arrow').click(function()
{
    current = (current + 1 <= 11) ? (current + 1) : (1);
    $('#produkti').attr('src', 'style/images/produktet/' + current + '.gif');
});
```

Comment: Care to comment your code? How does it answers OP question? Some comments are always welcome. This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Comment: Because I'm not an english native person, I prefer post the code in a first time and edit my answer after with the comment (like now). In this way I pay attention to my English.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea with data tags.

HTML:

```
<img src="style/images/produktet/1.gif" data-slide="1" data-max="9"/>
```

JS:

```
$("#right_arrow").click(function(){
    var img = $("#produkti");
    var slide = img.data().slide;
    var max = img.data().max;
    if(slide <= max){
        slide ++;
        img.attr('src', 'style/images/produktet/' + slide + '.gif');
        img.data().slide = slide;
    }
});
```